# Asynchronous call to API

Tags: swift, api, uikit, barcode-scanner

I have a three year old barcode scanning ios app that has been making a synchronous call to an api with no problems until I was forced to use a slighly slower api. The latest version of XCode offer this advice: Synchronous URL loading of https://get-thumb.herokuapp.com/getThumb.php?objectid=20019 should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

The code below asychronusly loads an ArtObject with string data including a path to another api. How can I get the data from the second, getThumb api asynchronously and load it into the UI on the main thread?

```
func downLoadJson (forObject: String) {
    let myURLStr = urlObj + forObject
    print (myURLStr)
    guard let downLoadURL = URL(string: myURLStr) else {return}
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downLoadURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        
        guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
            print ("something is wrong in URLSessions call")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let anObject = try decoder.decode(ArtObject.self, from: data)
            /*
            print("object Name is \(anObject.ObjectName)")
            print("Creators is \(anObject.Creators)")
            print("Medium is \(anObject.Medium)")
            print("Titles is \(anObject.Titles)")
            print("LabelUUID is \(anObject.LabelUUID)")
            */
           gArtObject = anObject // this populates the global gArtObject with the local anObject so that the vals are avial in other funcs
            
            var displayText = "ObjName: " + anObject.ObjectName
            displayText += "\nCreator(s): " + anObject.Creators
            displayText += "\nMedium: " + anObject.Medium
            displayText += "\nTitle(s): " + anObject.Titles
            displayText += "\nObjectNumber: " + String(anObject.ObjectNumber)
            displayText += "\nComponentNumber: " + anObject.compNumber
            
            
            //--- UI update must happen on main queue THIS IS THE PROBLEM
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.objectDetails.text = displayText
                self.imageVW.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: anObject.imageSmall)

            }
            
            
        } catch {
            print("something wrong after download step")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        
    }.resume()

extension UIImageView{

    func setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl url: String){
        if let url = NSURL(string: url) {
           
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url as URL) {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: There is no `getThumb` in your code. If the problem is that you don't understand what asynchronous means and how get a value returned from asynchronous code, please read the series of three short articles starting here: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ But even better would be to switch to `async/await` which is a lot easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this the same way you are loading your JSON.

In the `setImageFromURl` function remove the synchronous call to Data and use:

```
if let url = URL(string: url) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        if let data = data {
             DispatchQueue.main.async{
                 self.image = UIImage(data: data)
             }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```